# .gitlab-ci.yml after_script section: how can I tell whether the task succeeded or failed?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, status

I'm using [Gitlab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/), and so have been working on a fairly complex [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/) file. The file has an `after_script` section which runs when the main task is complete, or the main task has failed somehow. Problem: I need to do different cleanup based on whether the main task succeeded or failed, but I can't find any [Gitlab CI variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) that indicates the result of the main task.

How can I tell, inside the `after_script` section, whether the main task has succeeded or failed?

Comment: So are you referring to conditional `after_script` or you are referring to result of the main task. You can consider storing the result into a variable. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html

Comment: @ArihantGodha I'm pretty sure that variables set in one phase aren't preserved in another. Worth a test, though; even though I accepted the answer below, this would be my preferred solution. (I'd set a variable `succeeded` to `0`, and then set it to `1` at the very end of the main script; I'd then test it in the `after_script` to see if the process completed.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of determining whether or not the task succeeded or failed in the `after_script`, I would suggest defining another stage, and using the [when](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when) syntax, where you can use `when: on_failure` or `when: on_success`.

---

Example from the documentation:

```
stages:
- build
- cleanup_build
- test
- deploy
- cleanup

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - make build

cleanup_build_job:
  stage: cleanup_build
  script:
  - cleanup build when failed
  when: on_failure

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
  - make test

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - make deploy
  when: manual

cleanup_job:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
  - cleanup after jobs
  when: always
```

Comment: Unfortunately `cleanup_job` would not if `deploy_job` is retried, and then fails again.

Comment: What if you wanted to perform an `after_script` that required the same `CI_JOB_ID`?

Comment: Or you want to inspect the docker containers running that failed... =(

Comment: that was not the question he asked and it does not help if I need to execute something in after script only when the job was successful or not

Comment: This would normally be my preferred method, but there is no guarantee the subsequent jobs will happen on the same runner if you use a pool of N runners and need the job to clean up the runner.

Comment: @JamesHarr: maybe that's why there is concept of tag on runners https://innersource.soprasteria.com/sbs-cloud/dbpp/mpce/components/sopra-banking-mpce-batch/-/merge_requests/242#note_5618837

Comment: @MichaelBrawn: passing previous CI_JOB_ID might be possible by using [artifacts:reports:dotenv](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv).

Answer (score 69):

Since gitlab-runner 13.5, you can use the `CI_JOB_STATUS` variable.

```yaml
test_job:
  # ...
  after_script:
    - >
      if [ $CI_JOB_STATUS == 'success' ]; then
        echo 'This will only run on success'
      else
        echo 'This will only run when job failed or is cancelled'
      fi
```

See GitLab's documentation on predefined_variables: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: In case someone bumps the head on this one, sometimes the status returned by this variable is running instead of success or failed. There is an open ticket here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27693

Comment: My jobs always stay running in Gitlab 14.4 ...

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam take a look at the link posted by gibertoni,
if it is not the same issue, open a new issue over at gitlab.com

Comment: `CI_JOB_STATUS` works ok for me (Gitlab 13.12, non-Kubernetes runner).

Comment: be aware that `after_script` has a [hardcoded timeout of 5 minutes](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2716) and that it [is not run on timeout of the job itself](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15603)

Answer (score 42):

The accepted answer may apply to most situations, but it doesn't answer the original question and will only work if you only have one job per stage.

**Note**: There currently a feature request opened ([issues/3116](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3116)) to handle `on_failure` and `on_success` in `after_script`.

It could be possible to use variables to pass the job status to an `after_script` script, but this also has a feature request ([issues/1926](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1926)) opened to be able to share variables between `before_script`, `script` and `after_script`.

One workaround will be to write to a temporary file that will be accessed during the `after_script` block.

```
test_job:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo "FAIL" > .job_status
  script:
    - exit 1
    - echo "SUCCESS" > .job_status
  after_script:
    - echo "$(cat .job_status)"
```

Comment: `exit 1` will stop the script and `echo "SUCCESS" > .job_status` will never run

Comment: this is the best solution for now

Comment: Wouldn't exporting env variable work equally well ? 
export JOB_STATUS=FAIL;  echo $JOB_STATUS

Comment: This does not work for me, because after_script runs on a different context than before_script/script

Comment: @Arith yeah, and it's exactly what was intended - you got `FAIL` in `.job_status` then. This is only for visualising how to achieve the flow, normally you put your actual code into `script` section and store job status at the end, so you can check against it in `after_script`.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to handle this if you want to setup `if failure` behavior.

```
scripts:
  - ./script_that_fails.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 || FAILED=true
  - if [ $FAILED ]
    then ./do_something.sh
    fi
```

*Note: Other examples also worked for me, but I find this implementation more faster and suitable for me*