# conditional after_script in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have written few jobs in `.gitlab-ci.yml` and my question is similar to this one [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867981/gitlab-ci-yml-after-script-section-how-can-i-tell-whether-the-task-succeeded-o). However, the answers provided and accepted doesn't work for my scenario.

The job has an after_script section which executes when the main task completes or fails.

Problem: I send an email alert based on whether the main task succeeded or failed, but I can't find any Gitlab CI variable that indicates the result of the job to clarify in the alert email.

How can I tell, inside the after_script section, whether the main task has succeeded or failed?"

If I use `when: on_failure`, then my question is when can I define my `when: on_success` job, since these jobs will depend on the job right before the one - so I can only execute one of these. I've been trying to find variables in [Gitlab Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html) for this, but couldn't find.

Also, in my after script - I can write if condition, but I am checking if someone can provide better alternate soltion

Comment: There is a **Pipelines emails** service in settings -> integrations for each project in GitLab. If your _main task_ means all the jobs with `allow_failure: false`, the **Pipelines emails** service may be helpful.

Comment: @BenLee this doesn't help me much because if the job fails, I do have notifications enabled for the person who has initiated the job, which gives the job failure message with the failure message stack, what I want is to perform a certain set of action, preferably write a well formatted email and send to a defined list of users.

Comment: Insert an `send_email` stage after the stage of your _main task_. In the new stage, define two jobs, with `when: on_failure` and `when: on_success` respectively. As [the jobs of the same stage are executed in parallel](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stage), these two stage will depend on the jobs in the previous stages. Will this make sense?

Comment: [Here](https://gitlab.com/limjcst/test/pipelines) is an example. I set the variable `RET=1` for the failed pipeline.

Comment: Note the answer is another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68398861/ - since 13.5, there's `CI_JOB_STATUS` variable available in `after_script`.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem: I send an email alert based on whether the main task succeeded or failed, but I can't find any Gitlab CI variable that indicates the result of the job to clarify in the alert email.

> Also, in my after script - I can write if condition, but I am checking if someone can provide better alternate solution

May be you will be interested in new `stage` to provide email notification job.

Example of full `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - notify

build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Your awesome script"
  allow_failure: false # it's here just clarify the workflow, it's false by default

email_alarm:
  stage: notify
  when: on_failure
  script:
    - echo "Your alarm notification to email"

email_success:
  stage: notify
  when: on_success
  script:
    - echo "Your success notification to email"
```

So, here it is: `email_alarm` will be executed only if `build_job` has been failed. And `email_success` will be executed only if `build_job` succeed finished.

If you need to provide some artifacts from `build_job` to email - use `gitlab artifacts` in `build_job` and `email_alarm/email_success` jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can set your custom conditions such as:

```
scripts:
  - ./script_that_fails.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 || FAILED=true
  - if [ $FAILED ]
    then ./do_something.sh
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the answer is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68398861)  - since v13.5, there's a `CI_JOB_STATUS` variable available in `after_script`.