# Gitlab CI re-run a job each time another manual job is completed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

Currently I have such pipeline structure:

| Lint | **Test** | **Deploy** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lint | test-int | pages |
|  | test-stg |  |

What I would like to do is when I execute either `test-int` or `test-stg` to execute / re-run the `pages` job to upload the latest artifacts.

What I managed to do so far is to execute the `pages` job when `test-int` is manually executed for the first time. If I manually re-run `test-int`, the `pages` job is not executed again..

Here is my script:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.27.0-focal

before_script:
  - npm ci

stages:
  - lint
  - test
  - deploy

lint:
  stage: lint
  tags:
    - build
    - docker
  script:
    - npx eslint . --ext .cjs,.js,.ts
    - npx gherkin-lint
  only:
    - branches
    - tags

test-int:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - dev
    - gib
    - docker
  script:
    - npm run test:int
  only:
    - branches
    - tags
  when: manual

test-stg:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - dev
    - gib
    - docker
  script:
    - npm run test:stg
  only:
    - branches
    - tags
  when: manual

pages:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - test-int
  tags:
    - dev
    - gib
    - docker
  script:
    - echo "Deploying automation reports to Gitlab Pages..."
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - branches
    - tags
```

Comment: You have to trigger the pipeline again.

Answer (score 0):

By default, GitLab won't automatically retry already-completed jobs when you retry an earlier job.

You either have to:

- rerun the whole pipeline
- manually retry each already-completed job you want to run

---

In principle, depending on the details of your pipeline, you *may* be able to automate this by providing an API key to your job and use the API to introspect the pipeline to perform the 'manual retry' solution on the job(s) you want to run when necessary. It'll be up to you to decide what behavior you want and implement the logic in a script.

As a loose outline, you may have a `after_script` defined for your `test-int` job that, [on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867981/gitlab-ci-yml-after-script-section-how-can-i-tell-whether-the-task-succeeded-o) will:

- calls the [pipeline jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs) to retrieve the pipeline jobs to obtain the job IDs and determine if manual retrying for later job(s) is needed
- If manual action is needed (i.e., is not the first run and the `pages` job already ran), call the [retry job API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#retry-a-job) with the relevant job ID(s) obtained from the first call

Writing your own service to response to pipeline event webhooks may also be leveraged to similar effect.